# One Page Scroll js with parallax scrolling effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a one page website, where I used onepagescroll.js plugin. But I need to make its scroll with parallax effect like this one https://www.cssscript.com/demo/fullpage-scrolling-framework-vanilla-javascript-wall-js/

and this is how it scrolls normally : 
https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/one-page-scroll-animations/

Answer (score 0):

How TO - **Parallax Scrolling**

Learn how to create a "`parallax`" scrolling effect with CSS
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp

example

```css
.parallax {
    /* The image used */
    background:blue;

    /* Set a specific height */
    min-height: 500px; 

    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<p>Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect.</p>

<div class="parallax"></div>

<div style="height:1000px;background-color:red;font-size:36px">
Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect.
This div is just here to enable scrolling.
Tip: Try to remove the background-attachment property to remove the scrolling effect.
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried this but it didn't help, because I am using a plugin not just pure html css

Comment: share your code, i cant help without your code part

Comment: It is exactly like this one because i used this plugin: http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html

Comment: you need to write some css ,look like my answer